# SQLite database query (Python, Bottle)

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.4, bottle

I'm trying to make a function where that returns the name of the logged in user if one can be identified or None if not. i want to do this by finding the session id from the cookie in the Bottle request if present, and using it to look up the user in the sessions table.

My code so far:

```
def session_user(db):
    """try to
    retrieve the user from the sessions table
    return usernick or None if no valid session is present
    """
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sessionid = bottle.request.get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME)
    usernick = None
    if sessionid:
        cursor.execute("SELECT usernick FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=?", (sessionid,))
        usernick = cursor.fetchall()
    return usernick
```

The table in database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sessions;
CREATE TABLE sessions (
            sessionid text unique primary key,
            usernick text,
            FOREIGN KEY(usernick) REFERENCES users(nick)
);
```

When i use the current code in my function i get a unit test error:

```
line 125, in test_session_user
    self.assertEqual(nick_from_cookie, None, "Expected None in case with invalid session id, got %s" % str(nick_from_cookie))
AssertionError: [] != None : Expected None in case with invalid session id, got []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`cursor.fetchall` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall):

> Fetches all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning a list. Note that the cursor’s arraysize attribute can affect the performance of this operation. *An empty list is returned when no rows are available.*

Since an empty list in Python is a false-y expression this normally works out well - when not doing explicit compares with False/None. Always returning *a* list also makes code that iterates the result set (or checks the length) easier because no special case for None has to be done.

Use the aptly named [`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) to get a *single* result *record*, or None.

Comment: is the rest of my code right ? sorry i'm not too good with python and SQLite

Comment: when using fetchone i know get: line 138, in test_session_user
    self.assertEqual(nick_from_cookie, nick)
AssertionError: ('Bobalooba',) != 'Bobalooba'. I'm guessing because its retreiving a tuple?

Comment: A tuple is not the same as a string.

Comment: is it possible to convert it to a string so that i can make the comparison or is there a better way ?

Comment: You could get the first element of the returned tuple (corresponding to the first column in the result set). In this case you need to make sure that there was a result first.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: How do you get the first element (part) from a tuple (or other sequence)? However, the None check will work with `fetchone` so the test case shown will pass.

Comment: Well on the last unit test i fail because it doesnt match the string usernick to the tuple outputted  through fetchone.

Comment: Then get the first tuple element (eg. column value) and compare that to make the other test work.

Comment: Im unsure how to do that i keep getting errors saying not subscriptable Or something. I looked around stack for ways to convert tuple to string aswell as retrieve elements from tuples. But the cases dont seem to be similar to my own. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: None is not subscriptable (which is why you need to ensure the result is *not* None when using `fetchone`) while a Tuple *is* subscriptable: `t = ("a", "b"); t[0]`

Comment: But i need to have a none return value if the usernick isnt found

Comment: You *get* None if it isn't found and `fetchone` is used. In which case *do not try and subscript/index it* - because it is None.